# How to disable virtual workspace on my laptop (without external monitor)

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, workspaces

it is possible to somehow disable the virtual workspaces only on my laptop?

I have a laptop + external monitor and I'm working on the external monitor and I'm using the virtual workspaces a lot.

But, I can't watch TV or MOVIE on my laptop cause workspaces are still "flying" as it is used and movie flying with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Just open *System Settings* from the system menu in the right upper corner, than
- select *Appearance* and
- in that interface go to the tab *Behavior*.
- Uncheck the box *Enable workspaces* and it should return to default.

As an alternative you might want to try out different dual-head settings under Screens?

Hope this helps,
Jeroen

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use workspaces (but JUST on external monitor), I want disable it just on my laptop. @Jeroen

Comment: Ah, right now I see. From the little I know that probably is not possible on lightdm. Why not try to make the video screen 'visible in each workspace'? Should prevent the flying. And you probably need Alt-space to get to that menu.